# 7-1 Hoare partition correctness prove

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to solve some problems from CLRS (Introduction to algorithms) and I'm having trouble with problem 7-1. Part b (for now) which reads as follows:

> The indices i and j are such that we never access an element of A
>   outside the subarray A[p ... r].

How would I go about proving it? I can see that the indices move towards the middle but... this is really twisting my brain. And explaining it isn't a proof. If anyone can shed some light on this issue I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: I think you need to include the algorithm, or at least a description of the Hoare partition.

Comment: This is probably a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Dukeling I probably should. But I figured that no one without the book could solve the issue.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes and thanks, didn't knew it existed.

Comment: I personally think it's way more likely to find someone without the book able to solve the issue, assuming a sufficient description of the problem is given, or said person is already familiar with it or finds this information elsewhere. Or said person might have the book, but it's not close-by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the following partition algorithm:

```
PARTITION(A,p,r)
  x = A[p]
  i = p-1
  j = r+1
  while TRUE
    do repeat j=j-1
         until A[j]<=x
       repeat i=i+1
         until A[i]>=x
       if i<j
         then exchange A[i] and A[j]
         else return j
```

A suitable invariant for the while loop is ***There is always an index a such that A[a] <= x and p <= a < j, and an index b such that A[b] such that A[b]>=x and i < b <= r***.

You need to show:

1. That this is true when the loop is started (Hint: choose a=p and b=p)
2. That if this is true at the start of the loop, then it is still true at the end of the loop. (Hint: During the exchange choose a=j and b=i)

Once you have established the invariant for the while loop, you can consider each repeat loop and show that the indices must stay in the range allowed.  (Hint: for the first repeat loop try to prove that j is always >= a where a is as defined in the original invariant)

Comment: Using a loop invariant seems to be the key to it, thanks